# The "I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally" does not show up

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've just installed tensorflow with GPU support from source though I had installed via pip before following the steps in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources.

However, when I import tensorflow I get this:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess =tf.Session()
2017-03-07 20:35:36.402490: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-03-07 20:35:36.402889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce 830M
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.15
pciBusID 0000:08:00.0
Total memory: 1.96GiB
Free memory: 1.75GiB
2017-03-07 20:35:36.402914: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-03-07 20:35:36.402925: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-03-07 20:35:36.403415: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce 830M, pci bus id: 0000:08:00.0)
```

As can be seen, the following lines do not show up

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: I met with the same issue, were you able to solve it?? Please check my posted question too :)